# How can I retrieve audio from Firebase into my app Android?

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, audio

**Summarize the problem** 
I just want to ask first of all if it is possible retrieving audio file ".mp3" from a DB like Firebase into my app in Android studio through a link? Can I have a situation like this?

[image]

**What I've tried?** nothing because I'm just asking if it is possible and how or which tutorial I should follow to do something like this.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image. For sure it's possible but you should try something yourself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.